# Get children from ListBox (gtk4)

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk4

When I was using `gtk3` I was able to access a `ListBox's` children this way:

```
let list_box = ListBox::new(); 
let label = Label::new(Some("Label 1")); 

list_box.append(&label);

for row in list_box.children() {
    list_box.remove(&row);
}
```

In gtk4, it seems like `children()` doesn't exist anymore: "no method named `children` found for struct `gtk4::ListBox`".

I checked [ListBox](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/git/docs/gtk4/struct.ListBox.html) in the `gtk4` docs, but I couldn't find anything related to accessing a ListBox's children.

How to access a `ListBox`'s children in `gtk4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [`observe_children`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/git/docs/gtk4/prelude/trait.WidgetExt.html#tymethod.observe_children), but like it's name suggests you should not modify the container while using it. Or more specifically you can't keep using it's iterator once you modify the underlying container.

For your usecase you can iterate and remove children using `first_child`/`last_child` like this:

```rust
while let Some(row) = list_box.last_child() {
    list_box.remove(&row);
}
```

Comment: But I think that won't work if I want to remove *all* children?

Comment: Yes the `while let` will. It loops for as long as there is a last child.

Comment: Oh, I thought that would only remove the `last_child`. Thanks again for the answer.